# AWS S3 presigned url with React uploads empty file

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, http-put

I am using React, API gateway, and Lambda (Python) to obtain a pre-signed url to upload a file to an s3 bucket. But the files uploaded to the s3 bucket are always empty (0 bytes). And for some reason, when I upload a CSV in my React App. The uploaded file in s3 turns into an .XLS file but still named the original csv.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="fileOne" onChange={fileUploadOne} />
</div>
```

...

```
const fileUploadOne = (event) => {
    const { files } = event.target;
    getPresignedUrl(files[0]).then((response) => {
      putToS3(files[0], response);
    });
  };

...

export async function getPresignedUrl(fileObject) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://<api_gateway_url>.amazonaws.com/<api_name>?filename=" +
      fileObject.name +
      "&filetype=" +
      fileObject.type,
    requestOptions
  );
  return await response.json();
}

export async function putToS3(fileObject, presignedUrl) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": fileObject.type,
    },
    data: fileObject,
  };
  const response = await fetch(presignedUrl, requestOptions);
  return await response;
}
```

My Lambda code (which is accessed with getPresignedUrl function):

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    params = event["queryStringParameters"]
    key = params.get('filename')
    filetype = params.get('filetype')
    
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    client_action = 'put_object'
    bucket_name = '<bucket_name>'
    resp = generate_presigned_url(
        s3_client, client_action, {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': key,'ContentType':filetype}, 1000)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", # Required for CORS support to work
        },
        'body': json.dumps(resp)
    }

def generate_presigned_url(s3_client, client_method, method_parameters, expires_in):
    """
    Generate a presigned Amazon S3 URL that can be used to perform an action.

    :param s3_client: A Boto3 Amazon S3 client.
    :param client_method: The name of the client method that the URL performs.
    :param method_parameters: The parameters of the specified client method.
    :param expires_in: The number of seconds the presigned URL is valid for.
    :return: The presigned URL.
    """
    try:
        url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod=client_method,
            Params=method_parameters,
            ExpiresIn=expires_in
        )
        print("Got presigned URL: %s", url)
    except ClientError:
        print(
            "Couldn't get a presigned URL for client method '%s'.", client_method)
        raise
    return url
```

Comment: What is the value of `response` in getPresignedUrl? AFAIK, the method returns the URL as a string - so the `response.json()` should not be necessary

Comment: @BertBlommers yup, it's a string. And yes `.json()` isnt necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my mistake. My HTTP PUT request should have the fileObject in **body** not data.

```
export async function putToS3(fileObject, presignedUrl) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": fileObject.type,
    },
    body: fileObject,
  };
  const response = await fetch(presignedUrl, requestOptions);
  return await response;
}
```

It was really very simple and a stupid mistake. Took me hours to figure it out.

Comment: Still not working .<Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified</Message>