# React upload image to s3 with presigned url from python lambda

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I've been following many many threads online regarding how to properly get a presigned url from a lambda backend and then use it in React with Axios to upload an image to s3, but I just cant seem to get it to work. Here are some threads i followed:

- https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-s3-presigned-url-react
- [AWS S3 presigned url with React uploads empty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68205761/aws-s3-presigned-url-with-react-uploads-empty-file)
- [How to upload image to amazon aws S3 using presigned Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277039/how-to-upload-image-to-amazon-aws-s3-using-presigned-url)
- [Call S3 pre-signed URL with postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479206/call-s3-pre-signed-url-with-postman/60742599#60742599)

I am either getting a `403` error (from axios.post), or `Access denied` (in Postman).

Here is my lambda code:

```
def getPresignedUrl(objName, contentType, fields=None, conditions=None, expiration=300):

    # Generate a presigned S3 POST URL
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
            "put_object",
            {
                "Bucket": os.environ["S3_BUCKET_NAME"],
                "Key": objName,
                "ContentType": contentType,
            },
            300,
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        logger.error("Error generating presigned url for s3: %s" % (e))
        raise
    except:
        logger.error("Unexpected error generating presigned url for s3!")

    # The response contains the presigned URL and required fields
    return response
```

Here is my frontend upload code:

```
const uploadImageToServer = (file) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const obj = {
        objName: file.name,
        contentType: file.type,
      };
      let response = await axiosInstance.post("/getsignedurl", obj);

      console.log(response.data);
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": file.type,
        },
        body: file,
      };
      const resp = await fetch(response.data, requestOptions);
      console.log(resp);
```

With the above code, I am getting the following error after making the `fetch` request:

```
{
    ok: false
    redirected: false
    status: 403
    statusText: "Forbidden"
    type: "cors",
    url: "wwww.presignedurl.com"
}
```

Any ideas for this? Public access is blocked on my s3 buckets, but that shouldn't matter if i'm using a presigned url right? Do i need to enable `"private" ACL` or `"public-read" ACL`?

**Edit** updated code

Comment: What are permissions for lambda? Plz validate the lambda is allowed PutObject, PutACL and the bucket can have public access

Comment: I am using AWS Cloudformation SAM templates, and yes put object, putacl is allowed. Cors is enabled on the s3 bucket, but I just checked (didnt think of checking this before) but all public access is blocked for s3 buckets on my AWS account. Is this the culprit?

Comment: `all public access is blocked`.. and yet you are trying to create a publicly available object. (I see you did edit the question). Does the issue prevails for private objects too? When you get a presigned url, can you put an object outside your app? (curl, postman,..)?

Comment: i'm only trying to allow my frontend to be able to upload to the s3 bucket. I dont think i need public access enabled for my bucket (seems like public access is for stuff like publicly hosted websites, and mine is an internal facing app). I wasnt able to get it working outside my app (using postman), i get the same issue: `403 error`. presigned urls should still allow uploads to a private bucket... so i'm not suer whats wrong